# Highcharts / HighStock - How to parse JSON correctly

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I’m trying to adapt this [Highstock chart example](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/compare) for use with my data. Here it is their working in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/compare/).

So I have multiple REST endpoints returning JSON in the following format (a collection of timestamps and decimals):

```
{
  "data" : {
    "1440151410002" : 0.00430013850798903,
    "1440151420001" : 0.00403626002690655,
    "1440151430002" : 0.00376276477784804,
    "1440151440001" : 0.00381307106855453,
    "1440151450002" : 0.0039385712356139,
    "1440151460002" : 0.0038632842565838,
    "1440151470002" : 0.00407696207243675,
    "1440151480002" : 0.0042298508094211,
    "1440151490002" : 0.00411973200243665,
    "1440151500002" : 0.00360435516702981,
    "1440151510001" : 0.00426992197206649,
    "1440151520002" : 0.00354089360750537,
    "1440151530002" : 0.00400806659263663
  }
}
```

As in the HighStock example, the intention is to loop over the endpoints and pull in the JSON before creating the chart.

In order for HighStock to read it correctly, I realise I need to map it to something like:

```
[[timestamp, 1.23], [timestamp, 1.24] ...]
```

I'm having a problem figuring out how to map between my JSON format for each series and that required to render the chart correctly, so I'm currently getting a blank chart.

My JS looks like this:

```
$(function () {
    var seriesOptions = [],
        seriesCounter = 0,
        names = ['P', 'Q', 'V', 'Q_C'],
        // create the chart when all data is loaded
        createChart = function () {

            $('#chart4').highcharts('StockChart', {

                rangeSelector: {
                    selected: 4
                },

                yAxis: {
                    labels: {
                        formatter: function () {
                            return (this.value > 0 ? ' + ' : '') + this.value + '%';
                        }
                    },
                    plotLines: [{
                        value: 0,
                        width: 2,
                        color: 'silver'
                    }]
                },

                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        compare: 'percent'
                    }
                },

                tooltip: {
                    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.change}%)<br/>',
                    valueDecimals: 2
                },

                series: seriesOptions
            });
        };

    $.each(names, function (i, name) {

        $.getJSON('/live/data/' + name.toLowerCase(), function (data) {

            seriesOptions[i] = {
                name: name,
                data: data['data']
            };

            // As we're loading the data asynchronously, we don't know what order it will arrive. So
            // we keep a counter and create the chart when all the data is loaded.
            seriesCounter += 1;

            if (seriesCounter === names.length) {
                createChart();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,
Hugh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a classic `Object` instead of an `array` in `seriesOptions[i].data`. You should do:

```
$.each(names, function (i, name) {

        $.getJSON('/live/data/' + name.toLowerCase(), function (data) {

            var data_tmp = [];

            Object.keys(data["data"]).forEach(function (key) {
                data_tmp.push([parseInt(key), data["data"][key]]);
            });

            seriesOptions[i] = {
                name: name,
                data: data_tmp
            };

            // As we're loading the data asynchronously, we don't know what order it will arrive. So
            // we keep a counter and create the chart when all the data is loaded.
            seriesCounter += 1;

            if (seriesCounter === names.length) {
                createChart();
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I updated the code as above, but I'm still just getting a blank chart rendered.

Comment: I can see the logic in what you've suggested and I appreciate the help, but for some reason it's not happening (blank chart).

Comment: Hi again :)  when I debug in Chrome, I can see that the forEach loop is only executed once and key = "data". This looks the problem, could the data object be nested so I need to go one level deeper somehow?

Comment: I see what is wrong. See the edit. You need to loop trough `data["data"]` instead of `data`.